# Jquery adding 3 input tags to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**EDIT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#add").click(function(){
var currentValue = parseInt($("#hide").val())+1;
$("#Recipe_table").append("<tr><td><input type='text' name='name[]'/></td><td><input type='text' name='quantity[]'/></td><td><input type='text' name='measure[]'/></td></tr>");
$("#hide").val(currentValue);});

$("#remove").click(function(){
var currentValue = parseInt($("#hide").val())-1;
if ($("table tr").length != 1) {
$('#Recipe_table tr:last').remove();}});

});
```

Add and Deletion works.

My question is, I dont want to delete all rows or ill end up deleting my headers aswell until there was no table in the first place.

Secondly, The value doesnt decrement when i remove, i simply copied above since it works and adds the value of the hidden field.

Plus, Is there a better way of setting the value, The above approach just increments without hesitation like for example.

Plus how i prevent it from not reverting back to its original value when i submit and back one page.

Comment: can you post the code you tried using jquery?

Comment: Do you want to add input tag dynamically?

Comment: For all those who posted closing tag. Read [Closing Tags Not Required](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/optional-html-end-tags-when-to-include-them.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the solution you got for counting the number of `<td>` is a good solution,
use

`numberOfTds = $("#table").children('tr').children('td').length;`

Comment: so i replace if ($("table tr").length != 1) with yours?

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your elements

```
<table id='table'>
<th colspan='3'> Table</th>
<tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='name1[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='name2[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='name3[]'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close your `</td>` tags

```
<table id='table'>
 <th colspan='3'> Table</th>
 <tr><td><input type='text' name='name1[]'/></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='name2[]'/></td>
   <td><input type='text' name='name3[]'/></td>
 </tr>
```

Edit: this will also work

```
<table id='table'>
<th colspan='3'> Table</th>
  <tr><td/><input type='text' name='name1[]'/>
    <td/><input type='text' name='name2[]'/>
    <td/><input type='text' name='name3[]'/>
  </tr>
```

Comment: where exactly you want to put <td/>

Comment: @user3205047, `<td/>` is not closing tag as far as XML goes. It should be `</td>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed your cell or table tags.  Here's the corrected html.  I had to assume where you wanted your final input tag...

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table id='table'>
           <th colspan='3'> Table</th>
           <tr>
              <td><input type='text' name='name1[]'/></td>
               <td><input type='text' name='name2[]'/></td>
               <td><input type='text' name='name3[]'/></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
        <input type='hidden' id='put int on how many rows added'/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how the rows can be added dynamically

HTML

```
<table id='table'>
<th colspan='3'> Table</th>
<tr><td><input type='text' name='name1[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='name2[]'/></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='name3[]'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="add"/>
```

Script

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#table").append(" <tr><td><input type='text' name='name1[]'/></td><td><input type='text' name='name2[]'/></td>        <td><input type='text' name='name3[]'/></td></tr>");
    });
    });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3e2MW/5/)

**Edit**

```
<input type='hidden' id='hide'/>
var currentValue= parseInt($("#hide").val())+1;;
$("#hide").val(currentValue);
```

Comment: what Jquery library version should i load?

Comment: I tried to sample this on my php. it doesnt work. Tried the script tag you suggested.

Comment: ah i saw it, i lacked );

I thought of it same as any function { }

Comment: I copied JQuery source code and saved it as jquery.js

but it doesnt load when i <script src='jquery/js'></script>

The html file, C:/www/folder/application/view/admin/jquery.js

same location with my view.

Or is it because of ci?

Comment: you can directly refer it online

Comment: var currentValue = parseInt($("#hide").val(),10);
var newValue = currentValue + 1;
$("hide").val(newValue);

doesnt add the value when i check page source

Comment: I will reaccept your answer. please help me with my value.

Answer (score 0):

You look like a beginner to HTML, CSS and JS(JQuery) so a few rules. Structure your code like so:

```
<table id='table'>
    <th colspan='3'>Table</th>
    <tr>
         <td><input type='text' name='name1'/></td>
         <td><input type='text' name='name2'/></td>
         <td><input type='text' name='name3'/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type='hidden' name="name4" value="The Text you Want to Store"/>
```

..but you still need to learn HTML before you can effectively use JS. With JQuery to can get the values of the table elements using:

```
$('[name="name1"]').val();
```

and set the value using:

```
$('[name="name1"]').val("NewValue");
```

Look at the website [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com) for HTML and JS help and [jquery.com](http://jquery.com/) for learning jquery

Comment: var currentValue = parseInt($("#hide").val(),10);
var newValue = currentValue + 1;
$("hide").val(newValue);

doesnt work

Comment: The code pasted doesn't make sense and is different than the original problem posted. Restructure your code, and use a simpler aproach.

$("#hide").val() will return the value of the element $("#hide") if it has a value.